# Finding the exponent of $2$ such that $x \cdot 2^a$ is as close to $1$ as possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

How do I find an exponent of $2$ that when multiplied with another number would bring the result closest to the positive side $1$? Like this: $y = x \cdot 2^a$, where $y\ge 1$ has to be as small as possible, $x \in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$,  and $a$ is the variable to determine.

This is for a program algorithm where I generate an infinitely zooming grid and x is the scale. Currently I just do this:

```
while (tScale > 1) {
    tScale /= 2;
}
while (tScale < 1) {
    tScale *= 2;
}
```

Since I was lazy at the time but I figured it must be rather inefficient and there's probably a more direct way to get the value.

Comment: Please let me know if you meant $y = x\cdot 2^e$. Using $a$ instead of $e$ would be a better choice of variable, since $e$ usually denotes the mathematical constant $e$.

Comment: oh yes probably a then, I certainly didn't mean any constant.

Comment: I edited it just now, y = 1 is a valid result. If y is 1 to begin with it just skips the 2 loops.

Comment: Yes, I saw the edit. The main problem I see is that depending on $y$, multiplying or dividing by $2$ may still lead to infinite looping, if the value you are multiplying or dividing is irrational.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I see 3 options: 1. y is bigger than 1, then y gets divided by 2 until its not and then multiplied again until its greater(just once in this case) 2. y is smaller than 1, then y skips the first loop and is multiplied by 2 until it is greater. 3. y is 1 in which case it just skips the whole thing.

Comment: If $x = 1$, $a = 1/2$, they $y = \sqrt 2$. You can divide or multiply this by $2$ as many times as you wish, but $y$ will never reach $1$. You need more constraints on $a, x$ to ensure that $y$ is always rational.

Comment: yes but a is what I'm trying to find out, a is the one that determines how many times its multiplied or divided so to speak. In my loop, at the end of each division or multiplication x is assigned the value of y. x /= 2 is the equivalent of x = x / 2

Comment: Can you see that $2^{1/2}=\sqrt 2$, multiplied by *any* rational number, $2, \frac 12,$ or otherwise, will *never* be rational, and hence, cannot ever equal $1$ (which is rational), no matter how many times you multiply or divide it by $2$. For example, say $x = 1, a = \frac 12 \implies y = \sqrt 2 > 1.$ So we divide x by 2 so x = \frac 12 \implies y = \sqrt 2/2 < 1. So we multiply by 2. So $x$ now is (again) 1.

Comment: a has to be an integer yes, x does not since y doesn't have to be rational. Didn't think of that since in programming all values storable in a variable are either rational or made rational.

Comment: Okay...just trying to clear things up!

Comment: I think i figured it out: var exp = Math.ceil(Math.log(1 / scale) / Math.log(2)); var tScale = Math.pow(2, exp) * scale; works great. or the equivalent in math terms: a = ln(1 / x) / ln(2) <- round that up to integer

Comment: Nice! Good work!

Answer (score 1):

OP  figured it out with the help of amWhy in comments:

```
var exp = Math.ceil(Math.log(1 / scale) / Math.log(2)); 
var tScale = Math.pow(2, exp) * scale;
```

"Works great". The equivalent in math terms: $a = \lceil \ln(1 / x) / \ln(2)\rceil$.

---

That said, I'm pretty sure that the original code in the question is actually faster. Computing logarithms in double precision  and then throwing out the fractional part does not look like an efficient thing to do.